# Symfony without Apache server?

Tags: apache, symfony

I just read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/apache_router.html) page saying that Apache is being deprecated and won't be supported in Symfony3. Is the process detailed on this page for if you're remapping 'old' projects that use apache web server to use the PHP web server? Or is this the 'deprecated' information that we shouldn't be using going forward?

Comment: No, there is written that "apache router" is deprecated, not apache webserver

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a real question, OP just read wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read them carefully. Not Apache is deprecated `Apache Router` is deprecated. Apache is the Webserver and "Apache Router" is a component. So you can use them in SF3.

Comment: Hey its not a problem and its the answer :D he is wrong :D but normally you're right.

Comment: I don't like "rep hunters" :) please remove this answer for community sake ;)

Comment: D'oh! Sorry guys - but thanks for the quick correction!